# I didn't found the database in Entity Data Model C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

This is my databases from Sql Server Management tools

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC0yJ.png)

And when I am trying to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model

I didn't find my applications database just system databases available Any one know how to show them ??

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BuPh.png)

Comment: `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` is not the server/instance you are connected to in SSMS. You need to connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Thank you very much it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use SQL Express very often, but it looks like your connection string is not right.

In your screenshot 1 it shows DESKTOP-VN2SRQQ\SQLEXPRESS as your SQL server\instance.

In screenshot 2 you have chosen (localdb)\mssqllocaldb as the server\instance.

Try changing the server to DESKTOP-VN2SRQQ\SQLEXPRESS